# Why does Thunderbird recompile faster after the first compile?

Tags: compilation, thunderbird

I compiled Thunderbird and am trying to recompile the complete sequence because I made some updates to some of the files. It recompiles much faster but is skipping the files that I changed. What is the reason behind this, and how do I do a full recompile?

Comment: Are you using `mach`? Give more info on what you changed and what you use to build.  If you use `mach`, try `./mach help` and see if there is a clean or full build option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not compiled Thunderbird for some time, but it appears that there is an option to remove the existing build tree by running a 'mach clobber' before you run 'mach build'.  That should ensure that you lose all current build data and start fresh.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/MozillaBuild